# Transform RGB image to *look like* Infrared

Tags: image-processing, transform

Context: I'm trying to improve a pose estimation model so that it works better when my camera is in Infrared mode. Unfortunately I only have RGB images to train on.

I realize that you can't convert RGB to IR directly, but my hypothesis is that converting the RGB images to look more like IR, and then training on a dataset of combined RGB and IR images, will lead to better performance.

Are there any libraries that have tried to implement a function like this? I'm essentially looking for a function that something like this ("IR effect") - http://funny.pho.to/infrared/

Comment: I have the same problem, and I want to convert RGB images to IR images (the ones that look like grayscale).
Did you find any solution?
I would appreciate if you share your search result if you found a way to do that.
Thx

Comment: @user57711 Welcome to SE.SP!  If the selected answer (the one with the check mark) doesn't work for you, [please ask a new question.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)  Please try to say what doesn't work about this question's answer so we can help identify the issue.

Comment: @user57711 SE.SP is not a discussion forum. Please do not post an "answer" that does not answer the question. As I said before, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without very much additional info, I'd presume the red channel of your camera has the highest correlation with the *infra*red spectrum.

Since you only have RGB and no knowledge of how that was calculated from the color sensor pixels: Take the R channel, it's as good as it gets.

The "IR effect" is for artistic purposes only. I'd doubt it has *anything* to do with what you see in an IR picture.

Notice that I also think you haven't *tried* to properly understand the physics of your problem: While I'd presume that a visible light photograph is highly correlated with a near-IR photo, that's very likely not the case for mid- and long-wavelength IR and certainly not for far infrared.

So, define your requirements better. And: ML really depends on having data. A lot of it. you might start with wrong data, but as DNN really don't lend themselves to *understanding* of the weights, it's very questionable that anything that you do with "emulated" data transfers to "real" IR data well.

Comment: When the camera is in IR mode, the IR filter is mechanically removed and the images look black & white. So to clarify, I think the images I'm looking at are near-infrared and look pretty similar to black and white images. With that said, should I just convert to grayscale or are there better ways to convert an RGB image to something more like near-infrared?

Comment: just drop everything but the R channel.

Answer (score 2):

The real result of the image is a combination of three channels with a different weight. 
The  IR mode of a camera just remove the IR filter(cutting over 2 um) letting the full spectrum of the light to reach the CMOS sensor. Silicon has high sensitivity around 500 nm (green light) so it is important to keep these information. I would suggest to increase the weight of red and reducing the blue one, before transforming the data into BW image.

Answer (score 1):

Near IR images are typically monochrome images from cameras where the IR filter has been removed, causing the inherent sensitivity of IR of camera sensors to dominate, and/or an extra filter that attenuates visible light.

Typical characteristics of IR images is that foliage become very bright, sky and water is dark, eyes become «creepy», skin artifacts are reduced. I think it would be hard to transform rgb images to simulate IR to the degree that you can train something to detect uniquely IR features on it.

http://www.wrotniak.com/photo/quest/_img/e510-ir.x.jpg

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/UV_Vis_IR_Portrait.jpg